# Prolog - can't run the program as expected

Tags: prolog

I wrote a course advisor system in `prolog`. Code is given below.

```
% A simple course advisor system
% The user interface

% Initialization procedures
start:-
    consult('info.pl'),nl,
    menu(ID).

selectedMenu(ID, option):-
    write("Wrong option!", option),nl,
    menu(ID),!.

%Displays menu to user
menu(ID):-
    write("Hello, I'm your friendly chat bot, I'll guide you about admission process eligibility criteria, examiniation pattern, fee structure, seat allotment etc."),nl,
    write("For eligibility criteria, I'll ask questions on your education and grades so that I can tell you for what branches you are eligible."),nl,
    write("For application process, I'll ask questions on deadline, exam date, exam centers, special instructions, syllabus, types of questions asked, scholarship etc."),nl,
    write("For application status, I'll tell you about BITSAT score of you, different cut-offs, seat allocated to you."),nl,
    write("For admission, I'll tell you about fee structure, payment details, payment status and confirmation etc."),nl,
    write("To proceed, please select any option from below options."),nl,
    write("1 -> Eligibility criteria"),nl,
    write("2 -> Application process"),nl,
    write("3 -> Application status"),nl,
    write("4 -> Admission"),nl,
    write("5 -> Quit"),nl,
    write("> "),
    read(option),
    selectedMenu(ID, option),
    nl,
    save.

selectedMenu(ID, 1):-
    eligibilityCriteria(ID), !.

selectedMenu(ID, 2):-
    applicationProcess(ID), !.

selectedMenu(ID, 3):-
    applicationStatus(ID), !.

selectedMenu(ID, 4):-
    admission(ID), !.

selectedMenu(ID, 5):-
    write("Good bye, it was fun assisting you!"), nl,
    % personDetails(ID, name), write(name),
    undo.

eligibilityCriteria(ID):- 
    write("Elgibility for BE degree.....").

applicationProcess(ID):-
    write("Application Process").

applicationStatus(ID):-
    write("Application Status").

admission(ID):-
    write("Admission").
```

When I run the code, I get below errors.
[image: error]
What am I missing here?

Comment: In Prolog, variable names must start with a capital letter. So at least `option` should be `Option` instead (in several places).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two types of warnings:

1. Singleton variables, i.e. variables mentioned only once in a clause. If they are truely unused, replace them with underscore. The first warning on line 5 shows that the variable ID has no value and useless in the start predicate.
2. Clauses with the same name & arity are defined in different places in the code file.

These warnings indicate your code has possibly some other problems not detected by Prolog. Solving them would solve these problems and highly advisable.

Concerning the run time type error, the number read was converted into an atom whereas the selectedMenu predicate used integers. You may rewrite selectedMenu with quotes around these integers e.g. selectedMenu(ID, '1'), etc.

Comment: @peter.cyc why would the input `1.` be read as an atom? It's read according to standard Prolog syntax, and in standard Prolog syntax this is an integer.